# Script question for BIND entry removal/add

Tags: bash, python

I need to or want to delete BIND DNS entries that are in File1 that match A records in File2. If the DNS entry has multiple records associated to it in File2, those need to remove too.

File1

```
car.example.com
truck.example.com
bike.example.com
```

File2

```
car    A    192.168.10.1
       A    192.168.10.10
       A    192.168.10.20
truck  NS   gtm1
       NS   gtm2
bike   A    192.168.10.5
       CNAME    trek.example.com
```

After the removal, I need or would like to add back new DNS entries into File2.

```
car.example.com      A    172.10.1.12
truck.example.com    A    172.10.1.15
bike.example.com     A    172.10.2.20
```

I tried a few grep. awk commands etc. I was able to remove the entry but not if the entry had multiple entries associated to it. However when I tried to start named.service it would fail.

```
grep -vwf file1 file2

grep -f <(cat file1 | sed 's/^/^/' ) file2
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Use bash? Use Python? Thanks

Comment: Where do the 172.10.x.x addresses come from?  i.e. how is a script supposed to know how to add those A records.    BTW the `bike` records in your example are broken and will fail any DNS validation test - a domain name can't have CNAME and an A record (or any other record). A CNAME is an alias pointing to another record.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record#Restrictions.  BTW, zone files are structured text and, like other kinds of structured text (e.g. json, xml, html) aren't suited to line-oriented tools like grep or sed.    You need to write something that 1. parses the zone file into a data structure, 2. modifies that structure, then 3. generates a new replacement zone file.  Note that resource records are tricky to parse.  There are two optional fields (name and TTL), and the order of the fields may vary (i.e. both "[name] [ttl] RR-class ..." and "[name] RR-class [ttl] ..." are valid).

Comment: rather than write your own parser, use [dnspython](https://www.dnspython.org/).

Comment: Actually, my comment above wasn't quite correct.  There are **three** optional fields, not two.  The name, TTL, and record class (e.g. "IN", "CS", "HS", etc) are all optional.  Only the record type (e.g. "A", "MX", "AAAA", etc) and the record data fields are required.